# if else javascript condition based on content div

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to javascript and I am trying to create a simple if/else statement that will display a different divs.

I need to display a div by javascript based to two div texts:

For example, if div.delivery.p.estado1 is "off" and div.online.p.estado2 is "off"
insert a div: `<div class "hello-world">onaire</div>`

If div.delivery.p.estado1 is "on", and div.online.p.estado2 is "off"
Show nothing.

If div.delivery.p.estado1 is "off", and div.online.p.estado2 is "on"
Show nothing.

Case 1:

```
 <div class = "delivery"> <p class = "status1"> off </p></div>
   <div class = "online"> <p class = "estado2"> off </p></div>
```

Case 2:

```
   <div class = "delivery"> <p class = "status1"> on </p></div>
   <div class = "online"> <p class = "estado2"> on </p></div>
```

I should use queryselector but I'm still not sure how

Any help will be greatfully received

Comment: what does your javascript look like in the <script> tag?

Comment: I had this:
var var1 = document.querySelector("div.delivery > span.status1");
var var2 = document.querySelector("div.online > span.estado2");

if (var1==off, var2==off){
document.write("<div class="hello-world">onaire</div>")
}
else{
delivery.style.display = "none1"
online.style.display = "none"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
let p1 = document.querySelector('.status1').textContent;
let p2 = document.querySelector('.estado2').textContent;

if(p1 == 'off' && p2 == 'off'){
    var seccion = document.querySelector("#miseccion");
    var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
    parrafo.className = "hello-world";
    var texto = document.createTextNode("onair");
    parrafo.append(texto);
    seccion.append(parrafo);
}
```

```html
<div class = "delivery"> 
    <p class = "status1">off</p>
</div>

<section id="miseccion">
</section>

<div class = "online"> 
    <p class = "estado2">off</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if you have any question please tell me

Comment: and if instead of a paragraph, I want to insert a div?

Comment: var divElement = document.createElement("div");

Answer (score 0):

I would just use 2 sets of divs and show the pair wanted, hiding the other pair.

```js
function myFunction(isOn) {
  var deliveryOn = document.getElementById("delivery-on");
  var onlineOn = document.getElementById("online-on");
  var deliveryOff = document.getElementById("delivery-off");
  var onlineOff = document.getElementById("online-off");
  if(isOn){
    deliveryOn.style.display = "block";//use block, inline, or inline-block depending on your needs
    onlineOn.style.display = "block";
    deliveryOff.style.display = "none";
    onlineOff.style.display = "none";
  }
  else{
    deliveryOff.style.display = "block";//use block, inline, or inline-block depending on your needs
    onlineOff.style.display = "block";
    deliveryOn.style.display = "none";
    onlineOn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.delivery{
  //css here
}
.online{
  //css here
}
.on{
  //css here
}
.off{
  //css here
}
```

```html
<div class = "delivery" id="delivery-off"> <p class = "status1"> off </p></div>
   <div class = "online" id="online-off"> <p class = "estado2"> off </p></div>
   <div class = "delivery" id="delivery-on"> <p class = "status1"> on </p></div>
   <div class = "online" id="online-on"> <p class = "estado2"> on </p></div>
```

I will admit I'm not a professional, so my code is likely to be flawed.

Answer (score 0):

A smaller version

```js
let firstStatus = document.querySelector('.status1').innerText;
    let secondStatus = document.querySelector('.status2').innerText;
    let onaire = document.querySelector('.onaire');

    if (firstStatus === 'off' && secondStatus === 'off'){
        let textEl = document.createTextNode('onaire')
        onaire.append(textEl)
    }else{
        onaire.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
  <div class="delivery">
        <p class="status1"> off </p>
    </div>
    <div class="online">
        <p class="status2"> off </p>
    </div>

    <div class="onaire"></div>
```